# Does using dispose objects if they are declared in a method

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose, using

Let's say I create a disposable object in a method, but I will call a using out of the method. Is then everything disposed in this method?

```
using(DbConnection connection = new DbConnection("myConnection"){

   SomeMethod();
}


public void SomeMethod(){
    var stream = new MemoryStream()
    // ... Do something with the stream ... 
}
```

Is the stream created in the 'SomeMethod' then disposed?

Comment: i think `IDisposable` is **not** chaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't be. Only the reference explicitly specified in the `using` statement will be disposed.

In this case, only `connection` will be disposed *after* the code execution leaves the using block. You'll need to also wrap `var stream = ..` in a using block, or manually dispose it.

Comment: That was fast!! Thanks! Is there something to implement such behaviour?

Comment: @Franki1986 No, there isn't. However, it's a good idea to have the *allocator* of resources be responsible for the cleanup of resources. It would also make things quite complicated; `SomeMethod` *might* want to hold onto the `stream` for some time, and explicitly wouldn't want a caller to free up those resources.

Comment: @rob, if we will have that mechanism - we will broke GC

Answer (score 0):

when we use Using keyword,it will call dispose method of object which is created in 
`using(Form m =new Form())` bracket. so remember we have to dispose manually if anything to dispose in the scope which is defined by {}

Example:

```
using(Form test =new Form())//test object will disposed by using at end of scope 
{//Scope start

//code written here or created new object are not disposed by using

//Scope End
}
```